# How to overwrite the PeerConnection constructor of WebRTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a server A ( server video chat use WebRTC ). in this server i have some PeerConnection Object.
I want create server B ( server monitor). in this server i want caprure the PeerConnection Objection of Server A to monitor. can i do it with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace RTCPeerConnection (2 places) with the constructor that you use.

```
    PeerConnections = {};
    var _RTCPeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection;
    RTCPeerConnection = function (pcConfig, pcConstraints)
    {
        var connection = _RTCPeerConnection(pcConfig, pcConstraints);
        PeerConnections.peerConnections.push(connection);
        return connection;
    };
```